# How do you find the magnitude of jw or iw?

Tags: complex-numbers

For a solution to a problem I'm doing I see its just w. How does that work out? If you find the magnitude you need to square it and then square root it, but j or i squared is -1 not 1 so I don't understand how they got that answer.

Comment: "*If you find the magnitude you need to square it and then square root it*" $\;-\;$ That's not what the (usual) definition says. If you quote the definition you are using, you'll notice the difference.

Comment: @dxiv so I need to multiply by the complex conjugate and then sq root it, in this case it would be -jw?

Comment: Either one will work. 1) $|z|=\sqrt{z \bar z}$. 2) $|z|=\sqrt{\left(\text{Re}(z)\right)^2+\left(\text{Im}(z)\right)^2}$. 3) $z=z_1z_2 \implies |z| = |z_1|\,|z_2|\,$.

Comment: @dxiv what do you mean either one?

Comment: Either of those answers your question in one short line. You still did not quote the definition that you are using, so it is hard to guess what part you are having difficulty with.

Comment: $iw\cdot(-iw)=-i^2w^2=w^2$, and since $zz^*=|z|^2$...

Comment: It's understood that $\omega$ is a positive real number, is it? Why don't you think of $i \omega$ as a vector in the complex plane, and simply look at it to **see** how long it is?

Comment: If you square $w$ and then square root it, then you get the correct answer.